# Sum 7 days after current date in Django

Tags: python, django, date

I Need to put an expiration date in a template, it show the current date and the expiration date will be 8 days from current date.

Can someone tell me how can I do it? Is possible do it with Django or do I have to do it whit maybe Jquery or JavaScript?

And I need to send it to my database too, not just display it in the template.

Comment: Answering your question: yes, it is possible. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-1443e0f14ad5dff07efd465e080d1110920673d8)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - When the calculation is just 8 days into future using `dateutil` seems like overkill when the python datetime library handles this case very well (with `timedelta`).  If needing to calculate intervals with weeks/months/years into future, than dateutil makes sense.

Comment: Eventually, it will arrive at that. That's the normal rule of working with date and times in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in django.  Have two `DateField`s in your model, both that could be blank and null.  On the first time someone views your page (with both dates unset), create a view for the template request that sets the one of the `DateField`s to `today = datetime.date.today()` and the other to `today + datetime.timedelta(8)` to be 8 days after the current date.  Save your updated model and then display that model in the template.